# Array from nested dictionary array Xcode

Tags: arrays, xcode, uitableview, nested, plist

I have created a plist file as follows, with all sections following the same structure:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>image</key>
        <string>gradient1.png</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Section 1</string>
        <key>list</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>questionTitle</key>
                <string>How are you doing?</string>
                <key>questionInfo</key>
                <string>questionInfo1</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>questionTitle</key>
                <string>What are you doing?</string>
                <key>questionInfo</key>
                <string>questionInfo2</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>questionTitle</key>
                <string>Where are you going</string>
                <key>questionInfo</key>
                <string>questionInfo3</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

I'm using this in a nested table. I use the "name" for the section title, and want to create a new array with different questions and their associated info..

```
- (void) setCategoryArray
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"QuestionList" withExtension:@"plist"];
    NSArray *mainArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSMutableArray *categoryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[mainArray count]];
    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in mainArray) {
        Category *category = [[Category alloc] init];
        category.name = [dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
        category.list = [dictionary objectForKey:@"list"];
        questionList = category.list;
        NSLog(@"%@", questionList);
        category.image = [dictionary objectForKey:@"image"];
        [categoryArray addObject:category];
    }
    NSMutableArray *questionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:nil];
    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in questionList) {
        Category *question = [[Category alloc] init];
        question.questionTitle = [dictionary objectForKey:@"questionTitle"];
        question.questionInfo = [dictionary objectForKey:@"questionInfo"];
        [questionArray addObject:question];
    }
    self.categoryList = categoryArray;
    self.questionList = questionArray;

}
```

Think its probably a problem with how I create the questionArray or the way I reference it in the label for the table (see below), but I get the same entry for every cell (but its not the first or last entry repeated).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SavedCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Category *question = (Category *)[self.questionList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    UILabel *questionNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    questionNameLabel.text = question.questionTitle;

    return cell;
}
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I have never seen `initWithCapacity:nil` before. On your `questionArray` why not just do `NSMutableArray *questionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

Comment: Thanks, I thought that the stuff from the plist would populate the array so would matter if started nil... Still showing the same thing in every cell though - any ideas?

Comment: Can you please explain what you wish to display. From my understanding, you have each section is a category list, and in that section are rows containing each question?

Comment: I would like to display "questionTitle" in each cell (see second block of code).. the questionTitles are in dictionaries, along with their relevant info, which is contained within an array for each section. The problem at the moment is that it displays the same questionTitle for every cell.. Thanks for your help

Comment: I have found that it is the first questionTitle of the final section that is repeated in every cell - any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I have found your issue.

You are setting `questionList` to `category.list` in the first for loop. That for loop finishes before the `questionArray` loop is run (So the second for loop will only ever run for one `questionList` - the last one).

I think the solution you are after, is to put the second for loop inside the first:

```
    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in mainArray) {
        Category *category = [[Category alloc] init];
        category.name = [dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
        category.list = [dictionary objectForKey:@"list"];
        category.image = [dictionary objectForKey:@"image"];
        [categoryArray addObject:category];

        NSMutableArray *questionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:nil];
        for (NSDictionary *dictionary in category.list) {
            Category *question = [[Category alloc] init];
            question.questionTitle = [dictionary objectForKey:@"questionTitle"];
            question.questionInfo = [dictionary objectForKey:@"questionInfo"];
            [questionArray addObject:question];
        }
        [self.questionList addObject:questionArray];
    }
    self.categoryList = categoryArray;
```

and then the question in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will be:

```
Category *question = (Category *)[[self.questionList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I haven't tested this, but hopefully it will work - or with a few NSLogs, allow us to get closer to a working solution.

Comment: thanks Patrick, i think you are right about the loops.. The questions are added to the questionArray fine, but the questionList is always null, whether i put it in the loop or outside it

Comment: Ah, there may be a problem with this line `for (NSDictionary *dictionary in category.list) {` if you put an NSLog in there, nothing should happen?

Comment: ah ok, I added a lazy instantiation for the question list, it's no longer always null, but only the questions from the final section are added to the questionList array. any ideas? thanks again

Comment: the `for (NSDictionary *dictionary in category.list) {` shows up fine with NSLog, and works through each section, the problem now is that only the last section's questions are added to the questionList, not sure why?

Comment: Done it! i was doing the `self.questionList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` at the wrong point, thanks for your help!